# AngularJS : From a factory, how to call another function in a cycle

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

This is my snippet of code:

```
_service.factory('$opSQL', [ '$rootScope', '$cordovaSQLite',

     function($rootScope, $cordovaSQLite){

         var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB(  "my.db" );
         var dbURL = dbConfig.remoteUrl;

         var opSQL = {
           deleteRow : function(row) {

              var strQuery = "DELETE FROM UpdateTo WHERE id = ? ;";
              $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, strQuery, [row.id] )
                 .then(
                    function(res) {  console.log ( JSON.stringify(row.id)); },
                    function (err) {  console.log ( JSON.stringify(err));  });
            },

            sendToServer : function(tmp) {
                // where tmp = [ { "id":1, "other"="..." }, { "id":2, "other"="..." } ... ]
                for(x in tmp)
                {
                    opSQL.deleteRow(tmp[x]);
                }
           }
         }
         return opSQL;
     }
]);
```

I think that the problem is in async of sqlite execution because the query finish with success but in the console I read only the first id of the list.

How to solve this?

Comment: You output only the `row.id`. Whar your you expecting?

Comment: When I call the fn "sendToServer", I'm expecting to see all the cycled id, but the output is always about the first element of the list.

Comment: I suggest you narrow down on the problem further. How often is `deleteRow()` called? You could place some debug output there.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, the function deleteRow should return a promise. The function sendToServer should also return a promise you can wait on. It should also collect the promises from the call deleteRow in an array and wait for all of them to complete. So something like:

```
sendToServer : function(tmp) {
  var promise = new Promise();

  var promiseArray = [];
  for(x in tmp)
  {
    promiseArray.push(opSQL.deleteRow(tmp[x]));
  }

  Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function() {
    // all successful
    promise.resolve();
  }).catch(function() {
    // something went wrong
    promise.reject();
  });

  return promise; // <-- the caller should wait on this promise
}
```

Adjust depending on function names available in the promise library you are using.

Hope this is useful.